# Chernikov Groups and layer-finite groups

Tags: group-theory

A group $G$ is Chernikov if it has a subgroup of finite index that is a direct product of finitely many groups of $C_{p^\infty}$ for various primes $p$ (quasicyclic $p$-groups). The subgroup of finite index that is a direct product of finitely many groups of type $C_{p^\infty}$ is the minimal subgroup of finite index in $G$, so it is characteristic in $G$ (in particular, is normal). It is called the radicable part of $G$.

My question:

Let $G$ be a Chernikov group and denote by $N$ the radicable part of $G$. Suppose that $N$ is central in $G$. Then $G$ is layer-finite, that is, contains only finitely many elements of any order?

Comment: If $N$ is central, then we can conclude by the Schur's Lemma that $G'$ is finite (If $G/Z(G)$ finite then $G'$ is finite). But I can not conclude that the question is in fact true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix some $n>0$. If $g \in G$ has order $n$ and $gh$ also has order $n$ with $h \in N$ then, since $N \le Z(G)$, we have $h^n=1$. But there are only finitely many elements of $N$ with $h^n=1$, so each coset of $N$ in $G$ contains only finitely many elements of order $N$. Hence so does $G$.

Comment: Thank you Derek Holt. Your answer helped me a lot.